# viewWillAppear equivalent in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am pushing a new scene & then poping back to the previous one, now I want to know whenever I come back because I need to reset a few things.

I was wondering is there a viewWillAppear equivalent of UIKit in Cocos-2D to check this scene is about to appear or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onEnterTransitionDidFinish` callback to achieve this. You can find the documentation here: [cocos2d 1.0 API](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html)

Comment: This does not work if I want to check if my application was suspended and then started up again in the same Scene. The Scene never stopped being the running scene and thus the onExit never gets called, therefore the onEnter will not get called again when the app resumes.